# PHP code that not prints me the backtrace

Tags: php

test.php

```
<?php

function a () {
    echo 1;
}
a();

?>
```

match.php

```
<?php

require_once("test.php");

debug_print_backtrace();

?>
```

Instead of printing me the backtrace, it prints me nothing

Comment: Simple answer is [Read the first example in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php)

Comment: Yes, but this example in the php website does not work anymore

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work anymore"?

Comment: probably because there is nothing to backtrace as where you call it, you are in the global scope and not in any call stack

Comment: Ah yes, but I want to know the difference between my whole PHP code and the one of the php website.... Why my own example no work ?

Comment: In your example you are NOT in a function. The call stack is a mechanism of calling a function of functions and correctly returning from that call to the right place just after where the call was made. You are not in a call stack, you have already returned from `function a()` so there is NO call stack to display

Comment: Don't worry about why yours doesn't work. Use theirs. The one that works. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

debug_print_backtrace() will print a line for:

- The function a line of code is in
- The `require` or `include` statement which led to a line of code being run

It will do that for:

- The line where debug_print_backtrace() itself is called
- The line where the function call or file inclusion it mentioned happened

In your example, debug_print_backtrace() is not in a function call, and is not executed as a result of an `include` or `require`, so it simply has nothing to do.

The fact that *before* running debug_print_backtrace() you have both included a file and run a function is not relevant - the point is to show functions which are *currently in progress*, not functions which have *already finished*.